# Batch Norm & Input Norm Comparisons

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, deep-learning, batch-normalization

Consider the following simple neural network which is trying to figure out a function with 1 input feature which directly maps to a y = 1 when X >= 12500 and a y = 0 when X < 12500...

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model

X = np.arange(25000)
# X = (X - np.mean(X)) / np.std(X)
y = np.append(np.zeros(12500,), np.ones(12500,))

input_1 = Input(shape=(1,))
dense_1 = Dense(20, activation='tanh', )(input_1)
# dense_1 = BatchNormalization()(dense_1)
output_1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_1)
model = Model(inputs=[input_1], outputs=[output_1])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([X], [y], epochs=10, batch_size=20)
```

For the most part the architecture of the NN is unimportant to me.

Notice the 2 commented out lines. I am going to permute uncommenting these 2 lines and report on the results and ask some follow up questions. I will call the first commented line input normalization and the second batch normalization.

You can make the assumption that I have a general understanding of the mechanics of how backprop, gradient descent and batch normalization work.

```
----- No Normalization ----- OUTCOME: Essentially 0 learning ----- 
Epoch 1/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.7042 - acc: 0.4983     
Epoch 2/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6979 - acc: 0.4925     
Epoch 3/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.7022 - acc: 0.4982     
Epoch 4/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6942 - acc: 0.5004     
Epoch 5/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6951 - acc: 0.4965     
Epoch 6/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6940 - acc: 0.5048     
Epoch 7/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6957 - acc: 0.5056     
Epoch 8/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6970 - acc: 0.4962     
Epoch 9/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.5040     
Epoch 10/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.6957 - acc: 0.5065



----- Batch Normalization only ----- OUTCOME: Essentially 0 learning ----- 
Epoch 1/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.4981     
Epoch 2/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6968 - acc: 0.5069     
Epoch 3/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6957 - acc: 0.4983     
Epoch 4/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.5018     
Epoch 5/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6925 - acc: 0.5046     
Epoch 6/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6979 - acc: 0.4964     
Epoch 7/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.4994     
Epoch 8/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6941 - acc: 0.5004     
Epoch 9/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6929 - acc: 0.4996     
Epoch 10/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.4987     



----- Input normalization only ----- OUTCOME: Extremely accurate @ epoch 1 ----- 
Epoch 1/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.1518 - acc: 0.9965     
Epoch 2/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0384 - acc: 0.9984     
Epoch 3/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0225 - acc: 0.9990     
Epoch 4/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0150 - acc: 0.9989     
Epoch 5/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0106 - acc: 0.9992     
Epoch 6/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0078 - acc: 0.9995     
Epoch 7/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0059 - acc: 0.9994     
Epoch 8/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0044 - acc: 0.9995     
Epoch 9/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0035 - acc: 0.9995     
Epoch 10/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.0028 - acc: 0.9997   



----- Input and batch normalization ----- OUTCOME: Slowly becomes very accurate ----- 
Epoch 1/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.2139 - acc: 0.9115     
Epoch 2/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0820 - acc: 0.9662     
Epoch 3/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0535 - acc: 0.9786     
Epoch 4/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0332 - acc: 0.9863     
Epoch 5/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0271 - acc: 0.9897     
Epoch 6/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0230 - acc: 0.9912     
Epoch 7/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0227 - acc: 0.9916     
Epoch 8/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0175 - acc: 0.9931     
Epoch 9/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0150 - acc: 0.9946     
Epoch 10/10
25000/25000 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 0.0149 - acc: 0.9940
```

Here are my questions...

1. I think I know the answer to this one but to completeness... Why
   does the model without normalization not learn anything?
2. This one is less clear to me... Why does batch normalization not correct this?
3. Between the 2 models with input normalization why does the one with batch norm learn more slowly? This seems to be the opposite of what batch norm is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should learn to inspect your tensors at various stages to understand what is going on.  It should be clear what is going on from simply looking at dense_1's output or the gradients.  And you should learn and understand the purpose of batch normalization and how neural networks work and learn.

Nevertheless, an explanation:

What is happening in cases 1 and 2 are that the values going into your tanh operation are too large and are being compressed in the upper part of the tanh function, leading to values that are all very close together.  That means gradients flowing through them will be very similar and not much learning will occur.

Why doesn't batch normalization fix this?  Well, it can, if you insert the batch normalization in the more common position: between the weights and the activation.  The goal of batch normalization is to have a nice distribution going into these activation functions.

So you should have a linear activation on dense_1 and then add whichever activation you want afterwards.  If you put it there, it will essentially do that input normalization, plus some additional theoretical advantages.

Another less ideal way to fix this in case 1 is to manually adjust the range of dense_1 weights based on your expected input ranges.  Then you won't need batch norm or input norm.